# probability of urnsample gives 0?

Tags: r

An urn contains 10 balls, in which 3 are white, 4 blue and 3 black. Three balls are drawn at random from the urn. I assign this to a sample space using the following code:

```
require(prob)
L<-rep(c("White","Blue","Black"),times=c(3,4,3))
M<-urnsamples(L,size=3,replace=FALSE, ordered=FALSE)
N<-probspace(M)
```

While calculating the probability of drawing three blue balls, I get the right answer.

```
> Prob(N,isin(N,c("White","Black")))
[1] 0.45
```

But, while trying to calculate the probability for drawing two white balls and one black ball, or for one ball of each colour, i get a returned answer as 0:

```
> Prob(N,isrep(N,"White","Blue","Black",1,1,1))
[1] 0
> Prob(N,isrep(N,"White","Black",2,1))
[1] 0
```

Is there something wrong with the code? Because logically the answers are 0.3 and 0.75 respectively. And if it works with the first case, why not the second and third, since all three should have the same code

Comment: Where are the `urnsamples` and `probspace` functions coming from? If you are using non-base R packages, be sure to explicitly name them in your question.

Comment: I'm using the prob package to use these commands. Sorry, I'm new to this. By non-base package, if you mean using in-built r packages, then no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be able to specify the number of times that a certain color will appear in your results.

Bear in mind that we are somewhat limited by the sample size that you set, which was 3. We can see the list of possible combinations of 3 colors and their probabilities in an easy-to-read format using `noorder`:

```
noorder(N)
```

> ```
>             X1          X2          X3       probs
> 1     Ash Gray    Ash Gray    Ash Gray 0.008333333
> 2     Ash Gray    Ash Gray        Blue 0.100000000
> 3     Ash Gray        Blue        Blue 0.150000000
> 4         Blue        Blue        Blue 0.033333333
> 5     Ash Gray    Ash Gray Ghost White 0.075000000
> 6     Ash Gray        Blue Ghost White 0.300000000
> 7         Blue        Blue Ghost White 0.150000000
> 8     Ash Gray Ghost White Ghost White 0.075000000
> 9         Blue Ghost White Ghost White 0.100000000
> 10 Ghost White Ghost White Ghost White 0.008333333
> ```

So from that table you can see that the probability of having 3 "Ash Gray" balls for instance is 0.008333333.

If we want to find the probability of having 2 "Ghost White" balls in the sample:

```
Q <- noorder(N)

Prob(Q,isin(Q,c("Ghost White", "Ghost White")))
```

> [1] 0.1833333

We can verify this answer using the table above:

```
> 0.100000000+0.008333333+0.075000000
```

> [1] 0.1833333

Let's make the sample size bigger and experiment some more.

```
M<-urnsamples(L,size=7,replace=FALSE, ordered=FALSE)
N<-probspace(M)
Q <- noorder(N)
```

With a sample size of 7 the probability of 2 "Ash Gray" and 1 "Ghost White" is:

```
Prob(Q,isin(Q,c("Ash Gray", rep(c("Ghost White", "Ash Gray"),1))))
```

> [1] 0.8083333

and the probability of 3 "Ash Gray" and 2 "Ghost White" is:

```
> Prob(Q,isin(Q,c("Ash Gray", rep(c("Ghost White", "Ash Gray"),2)))
```

> [1] 0.1833333

Comment: The isin command helps, but I cannot choose the number of balls of each colour i want withdrawn.

Comment: @NandhaKumar Oh, you mean like if you want 2 of the Ghost White and 1 Ash Gray? Let me look into that.

Comment: Exactly. I've been doing some reading, and what i found was we need to use either the choose command or nsamp(n,k) command and then multiply the answers we get. But, there has to be a way using the above method?

Comment: @NandhaKumar Happy to help! Feel free to mark this as the solution if it was helpful :)

Comment: It would be simpler if you use `rep(c("Ghost White", "Ash Gray"), each = c(2,3))`